# Installing Windows on an encrypted drive

Tags: windows, partitioning, truecrypt

Is it possible to install Windows on an already encrypted drive? Or do I need to decrypt it first, install Windows again on a partition and then recrypt it?

I just need to install some tracking software into a honeypot (which is obviously not my "main") Windows operating system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, there are really two questions you are asking here, I think. First, no, you can't do any operation on an encrypted partition without first decrypting it. Even an empty encrypted partition shows up as containing random values. If you installed Windows onto those random values, you would overwrite them and thus destroy the encryption (I'm not even sure if you COULD start the install, as Windows would probably say that the drive was full). When you use TrueCrypt to encrypt your entire system, it installs a small Linux OS atop the regular system that encrypts and decrypts the drive before Windows is even loaded. So, the system goes POST -> TrueCrypt -> Whatever other OS is below that.

If by decryption, you mean the REMOVAL of the encryption entirely (as opposed to decrypting it for use like TrueCrypt does), then you are still unlikely to succeed. TrueCrypt relies on being first in the boot order. If you installed Windows onto a partition that you had encrypted using TrueCrypt, it would not be set up in the way I described (with a thin Linux client atop the main OS). The Windows installation may very well succeed, but there would be no facility for decrypting the drive after POST, and so the system wouldn't boot up because it would detect the Windows partition as being corrupt or unreadable.

The exception I could imagine is that if you used a system with a hardware-level encryption, you could conceivably install Windows onto the drive without altering anything. Since the encryption/decryption process occurs at the hardware level, no additional software layer would be needed. But it sounds like you are using TrueCrypt.

Maybe you could expand your question a bit to explain more about the partition you are working on?

Comment: Well logically I'd say also that it's not possible to install another operating system, but thanks for shedding some light on this.

Comment: Glad to help, and yeah, I'm sorry if I wasn't clear. It's more a function of how TrueCrypt works - by placing that small OS on top of whatever else is in the system drive - that requires you to install the OS first, and then encrypt. Changing the installed OS means you need to remove the encryption.